# Powershell/Excel - Parsing/Splitting and exporting to excel

Tags: excel, powershell

I am trying to extract specific pieces of data from a text file and write them to an excel workbook.  Originally I was able to extract the data to excel, but I need only a part of certain cells, and so was modifying the data in excel, with only a certain amount of success.  I'm trying to single out the specific data in powershell before exporting it, but have hit a brick wall.
This is what I have so far:

```
#User input relevant folder location
$i = read-host "Please enter Folder Location: "

#import data
Select-String -pattern "     CISCO1941/K9     " -path "$i\*-Live.txt" | Export-CSV $i\InventoryRAW_Router.csv

#parse data
$RouterHNM = Import-CSV $i\InventoryRAW_Router.csv | select-object Line 
$a = -split $RouterHNM
$b = $a -join ","
$b
```

Which returns:

```
  @{Line=*0,CISCO1941/K9,FCxxxxxxxYR},@{Line=*0,CISCO1941/K9,FCxxxxxxxCF},@{Line=*0,CISCO1941/K9,FCxxxxxxxBN}
```

To be honest I don't know what to do next, when I try to export the data using:
    | Export-CSV $i\b.txt"
I get:
    #TYPE System.String
    "Length"
    "107"

and I can't seem to split the data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!
Thanks

further info:
sample text file data is imported from:

```
router01-Live#sh ver
Cisco IOS Software, xxx, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2012 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Tue 20-Mar-12 17:58 by prod_rel_team

ROM: System Bootstrap, Version xxx

router01 uptime is 1 minute
System returned to ROM by power-on
System restarted at xxx
System image file is "flash0:xxx.bin"
Last reload type: Normal Reload


This product contains cryptographic features and is subject to United
States and local country laws governing import, export, transfer and
use. Delivery of Cisco cryptographic products does not imply
third-party authority to import, export, distribute or use encryption.
Importers, exporters, distributors and users are responsible for
compliance with U.S. and local country laws. By using this product you
agree to comply with applicable laws and regulations. If you are unable
to comply with U.S. and local laws, return this product immediately.

A summary of U.S. laws governing Cisco cryptographic products may be found at:
http://www.cisco.com/wwl/export/crypto/tool/stqrg.html

If you require further assistance please contact us by sending email to
export@cisco.com.

Cisco CISCO1941/K9 (revision 1.0) with 491520K/32768K bytes of memory.
Processor board ID xxxx

DRAM configuration is 64 bits wide with parity disabled.
255K bytes of non-volatile configuration memory.
250880K bytes of ATA System CompactFlash 0 (Read/Write)


License Info:

License UDI:

-------------------------------------------------
Device#   PID                   SN
-------------------------------------------------
*0        CISCO1941/K9          FCxxxxxxxYR



Technology Package License Information for Module:'c1900'

-----------------------------------------------------------------
Technology    Technology-package           Technology-package
          Current       Type           Next reboot
------------------------------------------------------------------
ipbase        ipbasek9      Permanent      ipbasek9
security      None          None           None
data          None          None           None

Configuration register is 0x2102
```

and the excel output should be a simple list of hostname, serial number and model, the returned data shown:
    @{Line=*0,CISCO1941/K9,FCxxxxxxxYR},@{Line=*0,CISCO1941/K9,FCxxxxxxxCF},@{Line=*0,CISCO1941/K9,FCxxxxxxxBN}

contains the model & hostname from 3 different text files, and so I want to extract the 2nd and 3rd pieces of info from each array into excel.

Comment: Can you provide some example input and expected output (based on the example)?

Comment: I have added some further info, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Example, showing how you can extract hostname, model and serial from each file and export them to CSV:

```
$sModel = "CISCO1941/K9"
$sLocation = Read-Host "Please enter Folder Location: "

$cRows = @()
foreach ($oFile in Get-ChildItem $sLocation -Filter "*-Live.txt") {
    $cRawText = Get-Content -Path $oFile.FullName

    $sHostName = ($cRawText | Select-Object -First 1) `
        -replace '^(\w+)-.*', '$1'
    $sModelSerial = $cRawText | Select-String -Pattern "\*.*$sModel"
    $sSerial = $sModelSerial -replace ".*$Model[ \t]+(\w+)", '$1'

    $oRow = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        "HostName" = $sHostName;
        "Model"    = $sModel;
        "Serial"   = $sSerial
    }

    $cRows += $oRow
}

$cRows | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation outfile.csv
```

If you need to export to Excel, google Excel COM automation or use [Export-XLSX](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Export-XLSX-PowerShell-f2f0c035).

Comment: That's brilliant thankyou very much!  I've had to change a couple of things due to potential changes in input but your help has set me on the right path.